# gdb command 'info sharedlibrary' stucks on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb

So I compiled a gdb from source using target=arm-elf-linux and a gdbserver using host=arm-linux-androideabi. Everything works fine with debugging native code on android except that if I type 'info sharedlibrary', it's stuck.

I tried different sets of versions of gdb+gdbserver, including the ones from the latest google NDK, they appears to have the same problem sticking on searching all libraries currently loaded in memory. So I assume this is not the fault of me choosing wrong versions of gdb but the android system on phone.

Is it right? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Perhaps you can obtain the needed information by looking in the target processes's maps file in /proc?  You may need to use run-as to get a shell as that userid first.

Comment: In that way gdb will never get the correct symbol loaded due to lack of shared library base address.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Do you have exactly corresponding sources for these libraries anyway?

Comment: they are correct but they cannot match because gdb doesn't know where is shared library loaded..

Comment: Perhaps something has not been updated after the address space randomization change.  Can you figure out where gdb/gdbserver is getting stuck, for example strace it?

Comment: If I don't load symbols first, i can do all kinds of commands except for 'i shared'. If I use 'file' command to load symbols before I attach, then I will be stuck on 'target remote' command, which is the timing of attaching. I think this is probably because if you load symbol first, gdb tries to locate all the shared libraries in memory and stuck. And I will be trying strace tomorrow it's late here, thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37029/discussion-between-jay-and-chris-stratton)

Comment: You can try running program this way: LD_DEBUG=files ./my_binary.